# Priority in SQL queries

Tags: sql

Three tables:

```
Employees {EmployeeID, EmployeeName}  
Courses {CourseID, CourseName}
TrainingLog {LogID, EmployeeID, CourseID)
```

There's one position left in a course and the priority is to give it to someone who's never done a course before, then someone who has done courses but not this one, then anyone. The course must be filled.

Can the appropriate employee be found in one query?

Comment: What query have you currently got? Have you even tried anything? What happens if there is more than one Employee that hasn't been on a course. What happens then?

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a tidier way to do what I have done in multiple queries, a prioritizing mechanism that I hadn't come across before. I've been experimenting with boolean conditions not being evaluated if earlier ones are satisfied, but my success has me thinking I should go to bed or I'm barking up the wrong tree. I posted no attempts as I wasn't even close.

Comment: More than one employee who hasn't been on a course, just give it to anyone of them.

Comment: No, not homework--the last course I did was 21 years ago. I do always attempt to simplify my problems to make them easily readable, so it probably just sounds like homework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya.  It can be done.
Join Employees with TrainingLog on the courseId in question.

Some number of employees will not match yielding a NULL courseid.
order the set by DESC with NULLs first in the list.

rank them by rownum, and pick the first row.

if there is no first row, then there is noone to assign to the class.
otherwise, 
if the first one in the list will be the person to assign.

Comment: Pity the negative voters will mean others don't get to learn of the useful technique you present. Thanks. Note: I had to order by ASC to get NULLs first in the list.

Comment: Yep, and no comments on why it was downvoted.  I voted it up once.  It is the form of a question I once asked a coworker.

Answer (score 1):

base on the problem you want to resolve this could not be possible if you'll try to do it on query alone you have to work the logic with your application as well perhaps you'd love to create a stored procedure for this kind of conditions.